# Javascript to ignore Font Size in XML Code

Tags: javascript, velocity

Getting a bit stuck on the correct regex to ignore specific font size in a Apache Velocity template - as its set to font size 1 and rendering as tiny tiny font in a Lotus Notes email PDF render which looks like this:

```
<run><font size='1pt' name='multilingual'/></run></par>
<par def='8'/>
<par def='1'>hi all</par>
<par def='1'/>
<par def='2'>+1 555 3596</par>
<par def='9'><run><font size='9pt' color='purple'/>----- Forwarded by Jimbo on 19/10/203 11:16 PM -----</run></par>
```

I have this javascript thus far:

```
#if( $htmlBody )
    <div class='nx--mail-html-body'>
      $htmlBody.replaceAll(/(<font .*?>|<\/font>)/, "");
    </div>
#end
```

However it is not fixing it...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting all fonts to point 10 fixed the problem:

```
#if( $htmlBody )
    <div class='nx--mail-html-body'>
      $htmlBody.replaceAll("font-size: [0-9]+pt","font-size: 10pt")
    </div>
#end
```